# How to have Google Analytics track members-only pages?

Tags: google-analytics

As the title describes, does anyone know how this can be accomplished? Or is the regular setup sufficient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put the analytics code on your pages and it will track :)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://cutroni.com/blog/2007/08/29/segmenting-members-from-non-members/) is what you are asking about.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.